# How to add new fonts in CSS for local testing

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm currently making a webpage that imports the needed fonts from Google Fonts this way:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Italianno);
```

The problem is that every time I load the page I need to be connected to the Internet and it also takes time to load the font. Is there any way I can load the font offline because while testing the page I'll be refreshing it countless number of times and I might not be connected to the internet all the time and I don't want to wait for 3-5 seconds every time for the font to be loaded.

I tried installing the font in the system and then using it in the CSS. It didn't work.

Comment: If you install a font in the system, you should be able to use it like any other installed font. Check that you use the right font name in `font-family`. (However, if you intend to use the font on web pages, it is probably best to use `@font-face` during testing, too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey make a fonts folder with css folder and put the desired font there. Then in CSS call this code as example for MeriyoUI font as mentioned below. This would load the font onto your app.

For this you just need to download the font and put that in fonts folder. (pre-requisite).Try using web safe fonts.

Hope it helps.

**CSS**

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Meiryo UI';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/MeiryoUI.ttf');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** create a **folder** in website **directory** and **move** your fonts
    to it! ( `.ttf` , `.eot` , `.woff` )

*example: directory  -->  webfonts*

**2.** create a `css` document for that!

*example: directory  --> css --> webfont.css*

**3.** use this code into `webfonts.css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'name';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../webfonts/fontname.eot');
  src: url('../webfonts/fontname.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../webfonts/fontname.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../webfonts/fontname.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../webfonts/fontname.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

**4.** and in the first line of  `haed` element into your webpage, use bellow code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/webfonts.css" type="text/css"/>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 @font-face. Try making font face of your fonts from any fontface generator like this http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator. And to learn how to use them take a look in here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/