# CSS Font-Family

Tags: css, font-family

So, I'm brand new to web development, and I am trying to learn all about CSS right now. I noticed not many font-family's come with VSCode so I wanted to download some to get in VSCode to use in my CSS. Question is; how do I do that? I downloaded the .ttf file of the font I want to use in my CSS but I'm unsure how to get VSCode to recognize the font-family.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add new fonts in CSS for local testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113967/how-to-add-new-fonts-in-css-for-local-testing)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `@font-face` CSS at-rule:

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: myfont;
   src: url("myfont.ttf");
}
```

and then you can use it like so:

```
* {
   font-family: myfont
}
```

Comment: Took me a minute to fully figure it out, but I did! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://fonts.google.com/ to find the font you want, than select it and it should give u a link, paste it on top of your css file
ex :

link: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Antonio:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

using it: font-family: 'Antonio', sans-serif;

Answer (score 0):

First of all the fonts you use have nothing to do with VS Code. What you want to do is integrate your downloaded font directly in your CSS code which can be done like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(your_font.tff);
}

body {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Ended up figuring it out before referring back here lol, but again thank you!